# Can't passing data from AJAX to CI Controller cart session

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

This is my Codeigniter add_to_cart method

```
public function add_to_cart(){
        $data = array(
            'id' => $this->input->post('id'),
            'name' => $this->input->post('nama_brng'),
            'price' => $this->input->post('harga_brng'),
            'qty' => $this->input->post('qty_brng'),
        );    
        $this->cart->insert($data);
        header('location:'.base_url().'Produk');
    }
```

And this is my ajax. And what i'm trying to do is passing the harga_brng so it can be inserted into CodeIgniter cart session (as you can see above).

```
$('.equal').on('click',function(){
    var harga_brng = $('.value').val();
    var qty_brng = 1;
    $.ajax({
        url : BASE_URL+"Produk/add_to_cart",
        type : "POST",
        data : {harga_brng: harga_brng, qty_brng: qty_brng},
        success: function(data){
            alert('berhasil');
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, exception){
            console.log(jqXHR);
        }
    });
});
```

I got the alert. They said it success. but when i try to display the cart. it just not there. where the data goes? lol. can you guys help me?
And Before I try to pass the data using ajax i already make sure that the harga_brng variable is assigned with the right value (which is a result of java eval() from my simple calculator).

Comment: The Cart library is DEPRECATED and should not be used. It is currently only kept for backwards compatibility.

Comment: what does console.dir(data) show? put it in your success callback

Comment: @Vickel It returned all of my dashboard view code.